# Battery charger OR topology

Tags: battery-charging, nimh

Is there some type of simple topology that can work in the situation shown in the schematic?  This is a simplified version of what I want to do. The charger current and enabling will be MCU controlled.  The core problem is preventing the boost current from feeding forward through D2.

Options I have considered:

1. Multiple diodes in series (In place of D2) then PMOS bypass when 24V power below some threshold.
2. Some type of expensive specialized IC like one of AD PowerPathTM options
3. Charger enable OR'd with 24V supply comparator, output would connect/disconnect battery from D2.

[image]

Comment: Why does your boost charger need to be connected to "+24V" instead of being connected to "24V0-PF"?

Comment: At present it is that way because I have a shared fuse in the non simplified schematic.  24V0-PreFuse.

Comment: The problem would be the same either way I think.

Comment: You need a "diode" with a "threshold voltage" of 1.5 V before the end of charge, and a forward voltage at load current of 0 V. *Almost* possible with back-to-back MOSFETs. The problem is with a self-conceived topology. (NiMH? Why?)

Comment: Lithium has many other challenges, the problem would be the same anyway.